# Intellij IDEA,Maven,Git. Exclude from source control parent project

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

I have multi-module maven project (parent-child). And I want to exclude parent project directory and parent pom.xml from source control, i.e. only sub-project (child) should be under source-control. So, in my project the `.git` folder exist only in sub-project folder (not in parent project folder).

But when I import project to Intellij IDEA, it shows that parent pom.xml is not under source control and highlight it with red color. How I can "remove" from source control parent pom.xml?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? The whole project from parent incl. all childs should be under version control means in other words the .git folder only once on the level of the parent pom.xml file. Can you elaborate your use case?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need to have parent `pom.xml` where I will put all machine-specific properties. The child project is the main project shared between all developers on Git. And in parent pom.xml we define properties specific to each developer. So we don't want to put under source control parent pom

Comment: Make a separate project of the parent pom and put it under version control otherwise your builds will never be reproducible. If you need properties specific for each developer they should be put into profiles (I'm not sure if this is the best approach).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to the ignore list. Open the *Changes* tool window (mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> by default). Look for the pom file in the *Unversioned Files* changelist. (If not there, find it in another changeslist and revert/remove it). Right click the file and select "Ignore".